# Click sound in audio playing using web audio API

Tags: javascript, audio, wav, web-audio-api, flask-socketio

I have been trying to play a `wav` file which is received from the server as a `base64` string.
Everything works perfectly but there's a click sound at the beginning of the audio. I have checked the base64s string is corrupted or not [here](https://base64.guru/converter/decode/audio) and it seems fine.
So how to get rid of that click sound?
A complete working code is given [here](https://codepen.io/shyam3089/pen/XWxpRKm) with base64 string.

NB: Wav is a 16bit pcm(pcm_s16le) audio with sample rate as `24000`.

```
socket.on('playAudio', function (msg) {
    // msg.data is a base64 string
    var byteChars = atob(msg.data);
    var AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
    var audioCtx = new AudioContext({latencyHint: 'interactive',sampleRate: 24000})
    // console.log(byteChars);
    var byteNumbers = new Array(byteChars.length);
    for (let i = 0; i <= byteChars.length; i++) {
        byteNumbers[i] = byteChars.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    
    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
    var frameCount = byteArray.length/2;
    console.log("framecount:",frameCount)
    var myAudioBuffer = audioCtx.createBuffer(1,frameCount, 24000);
    var nowBuffering = myAudioBuffer.getChannelData(0, 24000);
    for (let i = 0; i < frameCount; i++){
        var byteA = byteArray[i * 2];
        var byteB = byteArray[i * 2 + 1];
        var result = (((byteB & 0xFF) << 8) | (byteA & 0xFF));
        var sign = byteB & (1 << 8);
        var x = ((byteB & 0xFF) << 8 | (byteA & 0xFF));
        if (sign) result = 0xFFFF0000 | x;
        nowBuffering[i] = ((result + 32768) % 65536 - 32768) / 32768.0;
        
    }
    
    var source = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
    source.buffer = myAudioBuffer;
    source.connect(audioCtx.destination);
    source.start();
    
});
```

Comment: Changing sample rate? Does it make any difference?

Comment: I tried it and no luck. I found a solution. If I remove first 40 frames `for (let i = 40; i < frameCount; i++)` audio plays fine. Tried with different wav files and found no problem. Not sure whether it's a real solution or not but works for now.